# How to add exception for this scenario in Anypoint studio?

Tags: exception, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I want to add exception when a user enters an invalid URL to call the endpoint in Anypoint studio.
Like my default path for calling the API is http://localhost:1234/api/flights, so I want a custom message "Something went wrong!" with a status code of 500 to be shown in an exception when a user enters bad path like http://localhost:1234/24api/flights. I have used APIKit router in this case. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is an invalid URI the HTTP Listener and APIKit should be returning a 404 (Not found) status code by default, which is the correct one for this scenario. Returning a 500 status code would be misleading.